# Shorewall is breaking packets/sessions when connecting out to internet

Tags: 10.04, server, firewall, iptables

I am happy to forward any further data if required like firewall rules etc.
Would appreciate if someone can skim through my config and see if there are any glaring errors.

**Problem:**
Everything working perfectly well then suddenly the system stopped working... (without any changes from administrator) (perhaps as a result of an auto update??)

All sessions through the firewall to the internet time out.
Sessions from or to the firewall (eg. proxy, ssh, mail, etc) all working fine.
Ping through the firewall works fine (because its sessionless?)
Browsing through the server works 100% if using the proxy but times out if going direct

**Environment:**
Ubuntu 10.4LTS server
Kernel linux 2.6.32-37-generic-pae
Shorewall 4.4.6
Iptables 1.4.4
pppoe v3.8
webmin manager v1.570

**Configuration**
IPTABLE LIST

```
root@gateway2:~# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
dynamic    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID,NEW
loc2fw     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
eth1_in    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ppp0_in    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
Reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info prefix `INPUT:REJECT:'
reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
dynamic    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID,NEW
loc_frwd   all  --  anywhere             anywhere
eth1_fwd   all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ppp0_fwd   all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
Reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info prefix `FORWARD:REJECT:'
reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
fw2loc     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
fw2net     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
fw2net     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
Reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info prefix `OUTPUT:REJECT:'
reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain Drop (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere
reject     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:auth /* Auth */
dropBcast  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp fragmentation-needed /* Needed ICMP types */
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp time-exceeded /* Needed ICMP types */
dropInvalid  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports loc-srv,microsoft-ds /* SMB */
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:netbios-ns:netbios-ssn /* SMB */
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:netbios-ns dpts:1024:65535 /* SMB */
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports loc-srv,netbios-ssn,microsoft-ds /* SMB */
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:1900 /* UPnP */
dropNotSyn  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:domain /* Late DNS Replies */

Chain Reject (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere
reject     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:auth /* Auth */
dropBcast  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp fragmentation-needed /* Needed ICMP types */
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp time-exceeded /* Needed ICMP types */
dropInvalid  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
reject     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports loc-srv,microsoft-ds /* SMB */
reject     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:netbios-ns:netbios-ssn /* SMB */
reject     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:netbios-ns dpts:1024:65535 /* SMB */
reject     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports loc-srv,netbios-ssn,microsoft-ds /* SMB */
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:1900 /* UPnP */
dropNotSyn  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:domain /* Late DNS Replies */

Chain dropBcast (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
DROP       all  --  anywhere             base-address.mcast.net/4

Chain dropInvalid (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID

Chain dropNotSyn (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN

Chain dynamic (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain eth1_fwd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
smurfs     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID,NEW
tcpflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
net_frwd   all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain eth1_in (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
smurfs     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID,NEW
tcpflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
net2fw     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fw2loc (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:bootps:bootpc
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info prefix `fw2loc:REJECT:'
reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain fw2net (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:bootps:bootpc
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain loc2fw (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
smurfs     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID,NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:bootps:bootpc
tcpflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain loc2net (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain loc_frwd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
smurfs     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID,NEW
tcpflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
loc2net    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
loc2net    all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain log0 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level crit prefix `net2fw:ACCEPT:'
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain log1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* Permit incoming traffic on certain ports */ LOG level info prefix `net2fw:ACCEPT:'
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* Permit incoming traffic on certain ports */

Chain logdrop (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain logflags (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info ip-options prefix `logflags:DROP:'
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain logreject (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain net2fw (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
log0       tcp  --  192.168.1.99         anywhere            [goto] tcp dpt:ssh
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request /* Ping */
log1       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] tcp dpt:ssh /* Permit incoming traffic on certain ports */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp /* Allow mail on SMTP, submission and IMAP */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssmtp /* Allow mail on SMTP, submission and IMAP */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:submission /* Allow mail on SMTP, submission and IMAP */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:imap2 /* Allow mail on SMTP, submission and IMAP */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:imaps /* Allow mail on SMTP, submission and IMAP */
Drop       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info prefix `net2fw:DROP:'
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain net2loc (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
Drop       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info prefix `net2loc:DROP:'
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain net_frwd (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
net2loc    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ppp0_fwd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
smurfs     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID,NEW
tcpflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
net_frwd   all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ppp0_in (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
smurfs     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID,NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:bootps:bootpc
tcpflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
net2fw     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain reject (11 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ADDRTYPE match src-type BROADCAST
DROP       all  --  base-address.mcast.net/4  anywhere
DROP       igmp --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain shorewall (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain smurfs (6 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  default              anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ADDRTYPE match src-type BROADCAST LOG level info prefix `smurfs:DROP:'
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ADDRTYPE match src-type BROADCAST
LOG        all  --  base-address.mcast.net/4  anywhere            LOG level info prefix `smurfs:DROP:'
DROP       all  --  base-address.mcast.net/4  anywhere

Chain tcpflags (6 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
logflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,PSH,URG
logflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE
logflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN,RST
logflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN/FIN,SYN
logflags   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:0 flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
```

Comment: Please zero your counters, `sudo iptables -Z`, try to connect to the server, then post (pastebin)  the output of `iptables -L -v -n`

Answer (score 1):

If you noticed this issue after and update (which sometimes happens) or an upgrade as such, is a regression and it is considered a bug. Please report it.

Bug reports ([How do I submit a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)).